# What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?

Tags: css, clearfix

I have the age-old problem of a `div` wrapping a two-column layout. My sidebar is floated, so my container `div` fails to wrap the content and sidebar.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

There seem to be numerous methods of fixing the clear bug in Firefox:

- `<br clear="all"/>`
- `overflow:auto`
- `overflow:hidden`

In my situation, the only one that seems to work correctly is the `<br clear="all"/>` solution, which is a little bit scruffy. `overflow:auto` gives me nasty scrollbars, and `overflow:hidden` must surely have side effects.
Also, IE7 apparently shouldn't suffer from this problem due to its incorrect behaviour, but in my situation it's suffering the same as Firefox.

Which method currently available to us is the most robust?

Comment: I use http://www.jqui.net/tips-tricks/css-clearfix/ it helps me hide the dot :)

Comment: What about IE 6 and IE 7? They never follow the right way of clearing things.

Comment: Now we're a year on, is there any chance of revising the correct answer to the modern three-line clearfix outlined [here](http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php), as used in big-name frameworks Bourbon and Inuit.css? See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16099501/1129420).

Answer (score 1068, accepted):

Depending upon the design being produced, each of the below clearfix CSS solutions has its own benefits.

The clearfix does have useful applications but it has also been used as a hack. Before you use a clearfix perhaps these modern css solutions can be useful:

- [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

---

## Modern Clearfix Solutions

---

### Container with `overflow: auto;`

The simplest way to clear floated elements is using the style `overflow: auto` on the containing element. This solution works in every modern browsers.

```html
<div style="overflow: auto;">
  <img
    style="float: right;"
    src="path/to/floated-element.png"
    width="500"
    height="500"
  > 
  <p>Your content here…</p>
</div>
```

One downside, using certain combinations of margin and padding on the external element can cause scrollbars to appear but this can be solved by placing the margin and padding on another parent containing element.

Using ‘overflow: hidden’ is also a clearfix solution, but will not have scrollbars, however using `hidden` will crop any content positioned outside of the containing element.

*Note:* The floated element is an `img` tag in this example, but could be any html element.

---

### Clearfix Reloaded

Thierry Koblentz on CSSMojo wrote: [The very latest clearfix reloaded](http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/). He noted that by dropping support for oldIE, the solution can be simplified to one css statement. Additionally, using `display: block` (instead of `display: table`) allows margins to collapse properly when elements with clearfix are siblings.

```css
.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

This is the most modern version of the clearfix.

---

⋮

⋮

## Older Clearfix Solutions

The below solutions are not necessary for modern browsers, but may be useful for targeting older browsers.

Note that these solutions rely upon browser bugs and therefore should be used only if none of the above solutions work for you.

They are listed roughly in chronological order.

---

### "Beat That ClearFix", a clearfix for modern browsers

Thierry Koblentz' of [CSS Mojo](http://www.cssmojo.com/latest_new_clearfix_so_far/) has pointed out that when targeting modern browsers, we can now drop the `zoom` and `::before` property/values and simply use:

```css
.container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

*This solution does not support for IE 6/7 …on purpose!*

Thierry also offers: "[A word of caution](http://www.cssmojo.com/latest_new_clearfix_so_far/#why-is-that): if you start a new project from scratch, go for it, but don’t swap this technique with the one you have now, because even though you do not support oldIE, your existing rules prevent collapsing margins."

---

### Micro Clearfix

The most recent and globally adopted clearfix solution, the [Micro Clearfix by Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

*Known support: Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 9+, IE 6+*

```css
.container::before, .container::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.container::after {
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

---

### Overflow Property

This basic method is preferred for the usual case, when positioned content will not show outside the bounds of the container.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
- *explains how to resolve common issues related to this technique, namely, setting `width: 100%` on the container.*

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  display: block;
}
```

Rather than using the `display` property to set "hasLayout" for IE, other properties can be used for [triggering "hasLayout" for an element](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

Another way to clear floats using the `overflow` property is to use the [underscore hack](http://wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html). IE will apply the values prefixed with the underscore, other browsers will not. The `zoom` property triggers [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) in IE:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  _overflow: visible; /* for IE */
  _zoom: 1; /* for IE */
}
```

While this works... it is not ideal to use hacks.

---

### PIE: Easy Clearing Method

This older "Easy Clearing" method has the advantage of allowing positioned elements to hang outside the bounds of the container, at the expense of more tricky CSS.

This solution is quite old, but you can learn all about Easy Clearing on Position Is Everything: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

---

### Element using "clear" property

The quick and dirty solution (with some drawbacks) for when you’re quickly slapping something together:

```
<br style="clear: both" /> <!-- So dirty! -->
```

#### Drawbacks

- It's not responsive and thus may not provide the desired effect if layout styles change based upon media queries. A solution in pure CSS is more ideal.
- It adds html markup without necessarily adding any semantic value.
- It requires a inline definition and solution for each instance rather than a class reference to a single solution of a “clearfix” in the css and class references to it in the html.
- It makes code difficult to work with for others as they may have to write more hacks to work around it.
- In the future when you need/want to use another clearfix solution, you won't have to go back and remove every `<br style="clear: both" />` tag littered around the markup.

Comment: It's not ideal to use hacks, but the :after method is a hack too! So, why not use the underscore method instead of the :after method? It's shorter!

Comment: @David Rivers: The :after method is not a hack as it doesn't exploit a parsing error in a browser, it uses a feature of css as a solution. Additionally :after will be supported in future browsers, unlike the underscore hack.

Ideally there will be a css property that can be applied to an element which will cause it to contain all it's content.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I find the :after "easy clearing" method superior to "overflow: hidden", as it doesn't crop CSS3 box shadows or positioned elements. The extra lines of code are definitely worth it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would `overflow: hidden;` be logical? I mean: what it implies is, that content that's too big to fit, will not be shown. While what we're generally doing here, is making sure the container stretches enough to envelop all content, even floating elements. This shows _more_ and doesn't _hide_ anything...

Comment: I switched from [Perishable Press New Clearfix hack](http://perishablepre​ss.com/press/2009/12​/06/new-clearfix-hac​k) (comes [gratis with Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/961876)) to [Nicolas Gallagher's Micro Clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallag​her.com/micro-clearf​ix-hack) after having some inconsistency issues across all major browsers and operating systems. It works like a charm. Thank you very much for the references, they where very useful.

Comment: I'm not advocating the br clear:both solution, but I disagree with your 'dirty' labeling of it.  The 'adding weight/load slower' argument seems silly, as it's 1 short line of html code, compared to the several lines of CSS (which your browser has to load too).  For the 'semantic value' argument, a br with clear:both is far easier to understand than trying to figure out a bunch of goofy firing squad css.  br clear:both is short and simple, and imho has no effect on 'professionalism'.

Comment: @Vigrond - Your point breaks down when it comes to large sites. Given the choice between 1000 clearing `<br>` tags or a few lines of css… I'm gonna choose the "cleaner" solution.

Comment: There's no need for `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` doesn't clear floats (categorizing it as "clearfix" is a misnomer); instead it causes an element to create a new [formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) within which the floats can be contained. This causes the container to stretch to the height of the floats in order to contain them. There is no clearance involved whatsoever - that being said, you can still choose to clear, or not clear, the floats within the container depending on your layout.

Comment: We should not be supporting IE7 any more. Please update this with the **three-line** method described [here](http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php)

Comment: @tomeoftom Supporting IE7 is not always the developer's choice. Unfortunately there are still projects out there that demand support for legacy IE versions, whether we like it or not.

Comment: @MichałGancarski Those projects, if offered, should be declined. Please see [my full answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16099501/1129420) below.

Comment: The last method using a BR tag is a single, small HTML tag and you're complaining that it adds file size to the HTML file, while your other solutions are multiple lines of CSS and still require `class="clearfix"` in the HTML if you plan on using it more than once. Yeah, it's not pretty and clean, but neither are most of the other hacks developers need to use on a daily basis to get their site looking nice in all browsers. The BR solution is cross-browser compatible, backwards compatible, and very lightweight. You shouldn't disregard it just because it's not pure CSS.

Comment: @Gavin - the problem with the `<br>` solution is that you're putting presentation in your markup. This makes reusing the markup more difficult if you don't want the `<br>` in another context. Answer updated.

Comment: Regarding the 'Beat That ClearFix' solution, is display:table necessary, or is it interchangeable with display:block?

Comment: @JackWilliam - "The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements." (source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack)

Comment: How about writing correct css to avoid any workarounds?

Comment: `overflow-y:hidden` (instead of `overflow:hidden`), reduces one more side-effect of that approach.

Comment: Is the ":after" Pseudo-element method the only one, which allows collapsing vertical margins? And shouldn't be this the preferable method? Imagine that you have two contiguous containers which are clearfixed. In the first one, you have an element:last-child with margin bottom. In the second one you have an element:first-child with margin-top. I think those margins should collapse but this is not the case, if you are using the "Beat That ClearFix" or Mirco clearfix method.

Comment: @BeauSmith, I hope you don't mind; I've taken the liberty of adding information about [Thierry Koblentz’ latest clearfix article](http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/) to your answer. Please review it and make any corrections you see fit. I did my best to match the general tone and style of the rest of your answer.

Comment: What is the point of setting the container `display: inline-block;` and then redefining it to `block` in the last example?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Follow the link for more info. You'll read that it's a Win/IE fix.

Comment: @BeauSmith following the link, I see something different: they set `inline-block` for Mac IE (which ceased to exist more than a decade ago) and then return the `block` value _for (old) Win IE only_ (via IE proprietary mechanism called Conditional Comments) _along with classic IE `zoom:1` hasLayout switch_. So `inline-block` doesn't take part in Win IE fixing, and in your example it seems to be just ignored. Also, it's a bit strange to see caring about IE5- and not caring about IE8 (`::` syntax) in the same code:)

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - Thanks, much appreciated. I've updated the whole answer. Since this solution is aging, I decided to simply link to the solution rather than summarizing.

Answer (score 73):

### What problems are we trying to solve?

There are two important considerations when floating stuff:

1. **Containing descendant floats.** This means that the element in question makes itself tall enough to wrap all floating descendants. (They don't hang outside.)

   [image: Floating content hanging outside its container]
2. **Insulating descendants from outside floats.** This means that descendants inside of an element should be able to use `clear: both` and have it not interact with floats outside the element.

   [image: <code>clear: both</code> interacting with a float elsewhere in the DOM]

### Block formatting contexts

There's only one way to do both of these. And that is to establish a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/block_formatting_context). Elements that establish a block formatting context are an insulated rectangle in which floats interact with each other. A block formatting context will always be tall enough to visually wrap its floating descendants, and no floats outside of a block formatting context may interact with elements inside. This two-way insulation is exactly what you want. In IE, this same concept is called [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html), which can be set via `zoom: 1`.

There are several ways to establish a block formatting context, but the solution I recommend is `display: inline-block` with `width: 100%`. (Of course, there are the [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding) with using `width: 100%`, so use `box-sizing: border-box` or put `padding`, `margin`, and `border` on a different element.)

### The most robust solution

Probably the most common application of floats is the two-column layout. (Can be extended to three columns.)

First the markup structure.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar<br/>sidebar<br/>sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-content">
      main content
      <span style="clear: both">
        main content that uses <code>clear: both</code>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now the CSS.

```css
/* Should contain all floated and non-floated content, so it needs to
 * establish a new block formatting context without using overflow: hidden.
 */
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  zoom: 1; /* new block formatting context via hasLayout for IE 6/7 */
}

/* Fixed-width floated sidebar. */
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}

/* Needs to make space for the sidebar. */
.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
}

/* Establishes a new block formatting context to insulate descendants from
 * the floating sidebar. */
.main-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  zoom: 1; /* new block formatting context via hasLayout for IE 6/7 */
}
```

### Try it yourself

Go to [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/eciwev/1/edit) to play around with the code and see how this solution is built from the ground up.

### Traditional clearfix methods considered harmful

The problem with the traditional [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) [solutions](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) is that they use two different rendering concepts to achieve the same goal for IE and everyone else. In IE they use hasLayout to establish a new block formatting context, but for everyone else they use generated boxes (`:after`) with `clear: both`, which does not establish a new block formatting context. This means things won't behave the same in all situations. For an explanation of why this is bad, see [Everything you Know about Clearfix is Wrong](http://www.cssmojo.com/clearfix_block-formatting-context_and_hasLayout/).

Comment: What are "the usual caveats with using `width: 100%`"? Also, are you suggesting to use `zoom: 1` in ¶1 of §2?

Comment: Interesting answer, but what about `overflow: hidden`, what rendering concept does that invoke? And how can it be different to `hasLayout`?

Comment: True, but if one avoids using `position: absolute`, then it's fine and will be part of the same rendering concept?

Comment: I see. By rendering concept I meant if `overflow: hidden` enforces such a thing that differs to what hasLayout does?

Comment: Thank you, so to confirm: the `overflow: hidden` and `hasLayout` are in the same block formatting context, while the others you suggested towards the end are different?

Comment: So cases of `hasLayout` include some of the CSS declarations mentioned? Or are they all independent?

Comment: Read more about `hasLayout` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794350/what-is-haslayout. I think of it as synonymous with establishing a new block formatting context. Elements that do this are essentially responsible for the layout of all of their descendant elements. One result of this is that elements that establish a new block formatting context contain floated descendants and floats outside of the element don't interact with `clear: left|right|both` elements inside. (This is in the answer above.)

Answer (score 56):

The newest standard, as used by [Inuit.css](http://inuitcss.com/) and [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io) - two very widely used and well-maintained CSS/Sass frameworks:

```css
.btcf:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

---

#### Notes

Keep in mind that clearfixes are essentially a hack for what flexbox layouts can now provide in a [much easier and smarter way](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/). CSS floats were originally designed for inline content to flow around - like images in a long textual article - and not for grid layouts and the like. Unless you're specifically targeting old (not Edge) Internet Explorer, your [target browsers support flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), so it's worth the time to learn.

This doesn't support IE7. You **shouldn't** be supporting IE7. Doing so continues to expose users to unfixed security exploits and makes life harder for all other web developers, as it reduces the pressure on users and organisations to switch to safer modern browsers.

This clearfix was [announced and explained by Thierry Koblentz](http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php) in July 2012. It sheds unnecessary weight from [Nicolas Gallagher's 2011 micro-clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). In the process, it frees a pseudo-element for your own use. This has been updated to use `display: block` rather than `display: table` (again, credit to Thierry Koblentz).

Comment: I hope your answer gets more up votes on this as I totally agree with you. Again, it's 2013 and I truly believe this is the solution people should be using.

Comment: Agreed. http://theie7countdown.com/ Check your own analytics and hopefully see IE7 is not worth your time.

Comment: @Justin agreed; your personal analytics will lay this out. I don't think that countdown site has been updated in a while, though - best to use [caniuse's stats](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php) which put IE7 at 0.39% globally.

Comment: Hopefully, hacks like the clearfix will soon be rendered unnecessary through use of flexbox, rather than floats, for layout.

Comment: You can object to supporting IE7 as much as you want, but if there's a requirement from the business end to support these users (for different reasons - typically money), you're going to do it no matter how you feel on the issue

Comment: @KrisSelbekk encouraging users to remain in an environment where they're exposed to known security risks for the sake of (likely very little) profit is unethical. You always have the option of rejecting the job, even though it would probably never need to come to that: in many situations you could make the case that your added development time spent supporting IE7 costs more than the income from a paltry IE7 user base.

Comment: @iono - very true in most cases - not in all though. But the percentage of visits (profits) coming from IE7 users are less and less every day, so hopefully we can make the jump to at least IE8 or IE9 sometime this year :)

Answer (score 29):

I recommend using the following, which is taken from http://html5boilerplate.com/

```
/* >> The Magnificent CLEARFIX << */
```

```css
.clearfix:after { 
  content: "."; 
  display: block; 
  height: 0; 
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.clearfix { 
  display: inline-block;  
}
* html .clearfix {  
  height: 1%;  
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clearfix {  
  display: block;  
}
```

Comment: Who remembers IE-mac now? Why make things so complicated because of problems that are no more relevant?

Answer (score 25):

The overflow property can be used to clear floats with no additional mark-up:

```css
.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

This works for all browsers except IE6, where all you need to do is enable hasLayout (zoom being my preferred method):

```css
.container { zoom: 1; }
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: overflow: hidden doesn't work in the PS3 browser.  Not that most people need that to work, but it is the most significant thing blowing up my site in PS3 which we are trying to target for business reasons.  Ugh.

Comment: And it's a problem if you actually want certain content to hang outside of the container.

Comment: overflow: hidden has a bad side effect of clipping content

Comment: `overflow:hidden` has the **effect** of clipping content; it has the **side effect** of clearing the container ;-)

Comment: overflow:auto will also trigger a block formatting context, and it won't clip the content.

Answer (score 18):

I've found a bug in the official CLEARFIX-Method:
The DOT doesn't have a font-size.
And if you set the `height = 0` and the first Element in your DOM-Tree has the class "clearfix" you'll allways have a margin at the bottom of the page of 12px :)

You have to fix it like this:

```
/* float clearing for everyone else */
.clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

It's now part of the YAML-Layout ... Just take a look at it - it's very interesting!
http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html

Answer (score 16):

This is quite a tidy solution:

```css
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}
```

> It's known to work in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 9+, IE 6+
>
> Including the :before selector is not necessary to clear the floats,
>   but it prevents top-margins from collapsing in modern browsers. This
>   ensures that there is visual consistency with IE 6/7 when zoom:1 is
>   applied.

From http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Yes, as of mid-2011, this is my favourite solution.  It allows you to position objects outside the containing box if necessary (avoiding `overflow: hidden`).

Answer (score 11):

Clearfix from bootstrap:

```css
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap is this from?

Answer (score 9):

I just use :-

```
.clear:after{
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Works best and compatible with IE8+ :)

Comment: Won't work in IE7 as it has no support for CSS pseudoelements.

Comment: ... That is why he said "compatible with IE8+." Most websites don't need to support IE7 anymore, it's usage is less than 1% worldwide. http://theie7countdown.com/

Answer (score 9):

Given the huge amount of replies I was not gonna post. However, this method may help someone, as it did help me.

### Stay way from floats whenever possible

It's worth to mention, I avoid floats like Ebola. There are many reasons and I am not alone; Read Rikudo answer about [what is a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) and you'll see what I mean. In his own words: `...the use of floated elements for layout is getting more and more discouraged with the use of better alternatives...`

There are other good (and sometimes better) options out there other than floats. As technology advances and improves, [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) (and other methods) are going to be widely adopted and floats will become just a bad memory. Maybe a CSS4?

---

### Float misbehavior and failed clears

First off, sometimes, you may think that you are safe from floats until your lifesaver is punctured and your html flow starts to sink:

In the codepen http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/jEXBya below, the practice of clearing a float with `<div classs="clear"></div>` (or other element) is common but frown upon and anti-semantic.

```
<div class="floated">1st</div>
<div class="floated">2nd</div>
<div class="floated">3nd</div>
<div classs="clear"></div> <!-- Acts as a wall -->
<section>Below</section>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

div.floated {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
section {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
}
```

**However**, just when you thought your float is sail worthy...boom! As the screen size becomes smaller and smaller you see weird behaviors in like the graphic below (Same http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/jEXBya):

[image: float bug sample 1]

**Why should you care?**
Roughly, about 80% (or more) of the devices used are mobile devices with small screens. Desktop computers/laptops are no longer king.

---

### It does not end there

This is not the only problem with floats. There are many, but in this example, some may say `all you have to do is to place your floats in a container`. But as you can see in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/XJoMYG) and graphic, that is not the case. It apparently made things worst:

HTML

```
<div id="container" class="">
  <div class="floated">1st</div>
  <div class="floated">2nd</div>
  <div class="floated">3nd</div>
</div> <!-- /#conteiner -->
<div classs="clear"></div> <!-- Acts as a wall -->
<section>Below</section>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  min-height: 100px; /* To prevent it from collapsing */
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
.floated {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
section {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
}
```

As for the result?

It's the *** same!
[image: float bug sample 2]

Least you know, you'll start a CSS party, inviting all kinds of selectors and properties to the party; making a bigger mess of your CSS than what you started with. Just to fix your float.

---

### CSS Clearfix to the rescue

This simple and very adaptable piece of CSS is a beauty and a "savior":

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

That's it! It really works without breaking semantics and did I mention [it works?](http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/wBRJaz):

From the same sample...**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="floated">1st</div>
    <div class="floated">2nd</div>
    <div class="floated">3nd</div>
</div>
<section>Below</section>
```

**CSS**

```
div.floated {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
section {
        border: 4px solid #00f;
}


.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

---

Now we no longer need `<div classs="clear"></div> <!-- Acts as a wall -->` and keep the semantic police happy. This is not the only benefit. This clearfix is responsive to any screen size without the use of `@media` in it's simplest form. In other words, it will keep your float container in check and preventing floodings. Lastly, it provides support for old browsers all in one small karate chop =)

## Here's the clearfix again

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

Comment: The reason why the element with  `clear` class name not work is that your attribute `class` is wrong. What you wrote is `classs`, with an additional `s`.

Comment: Your example does not demonstrate what you claim, even after correcting errors.

Answer (score 8):

I always float the main sections of my grid and apply `clear: both;` to the footer. That doesn't require an extra div or class.

Comment: Neil, I guess the trouble comes when you want a border around both your columns (or a background colour/image), you need a wrapper section which needs the containing hack.

Answer (score 6):

honestly; all solutions seem to be a hack to fix a rendering bug ... am i wrong?

i've found `<br clear="all" />` to be the easiest, simplest. seeing `class="clearfix"` everywhere can't stroke the sensibilities of someone who objects to extraneous markeup elements, can it? you're just painting the problem on a different canvas.

i also use the `display: hidden` solution, which is great and requires no extra class declarations or html markup ... but sometimes you need the elements to overflow the container, for eg. pretty ribbons and sashes

Comment: `overflow: hidden` I think you mean

Comment: Some recommend using class called group which makes things more semantic. I'm frankly not sure why this hasn't caught on

Comment: im totally retracting this position. i just use clearfix now. but on very common containers, i 'bake' it into the css to cut down on class attribute pollution.

also, naming it 'group' seems nice. less chars to type as well

Answer (score 6):

```css
.clearFix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;  
    clear: both;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A new display value seems to the job in one line.

```
display: flow-root;
```

From the W3 spec: "The element generates a block container box, and lays out its contents using flow layout. It always establishes a new block formatting context for its contents."

Information:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5769454877147136

※As shown in the link above, support is currently limited so fallback support like below may be of use:
https://github.com/fliptheweb/postcss-flow-root

Answer (score 5):

Using `overflow:hidden`/`auto` and height for ie6 will suffice if the floating container has a parent element.

Either one of the #test could work, for the HTML stated below to clear floats.

```css
#test {
  overflow:hidden; // or auto;
  _height:1%; forces hasLayout in IE6
}

<div id="test">
  <div style="floatLeft"></div>
  <div style="random"></div>
</div>
```

In cases when this refuses to work with ie6, just float the parent to clear float.

```css
#test {
  float: left; // using float to clear float
  width: 99%;
}
```

Never really needed any other kind of clearing yet. Maybe it's the way I write my HTML.

Comment: I would like to study your way of writing HTML without clearing any elements. Could you post some links?

Answer (score 5):

With LESS (http://lesscss.org/), one can create a handy clearfix helper:

```css
.clearfix() {
  zoom: 1;
  &:before { 
    content: ''; 
    display: block; 
  }
  &:after { 
    content: ''; 
    display: table; 
    clear: both; 
  }
}
```

And then use it with problematic containers, for example:

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

```css
/* LESS */
div#container {
  .clearfix();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With SASS, the clearfix is:

```css
@mixin clearfix {
    &:before, &:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

and it's used like:

```css
.container {
    @include clearfix;
}
```

if you want the new clearfix:

```css
@mixin newclearfix {
    &:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried all these solutions, a big margin will be added to `<html>` element automatically when I use the code below:

```
.clearfix:after {   
    visibility: hidden;   
    display: block;   
    content: ".";   
    clear: both;   
    height: 0;
}
```

Finally, I solved the margin problem by adding `font-size: 0;` to the above CSS.

Comment: That's because you're adding a line with `.`, just use `content: ""`

Answer (score 3):

I'd float `#content` too, that way both columns contain floats. Also because it will allow you to clear elements inside `#content` without clearing the side bar.

Same thing with the wrapper, you'd need to make it a block formatting context to wrap the two columns.

This article mentions a few triggers you can use:
[block formatting contexts](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/block-formatting-contexts_and_hasLayout.asp).

Answer (score 3):

A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear after itself, 
so that you don't need to add additional markup.

```css
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
.cleaner {
  clear: both;
}
```

Normally you would need to do something as follows:

```html
<div style="float: left;">Sidebar</div>
<div class="cleaner"></div> <!-- Clear the float -->
```

With clearfix, you only need to

```html
<div style="float: left;" class="clearfix">Sidebar</div>
<!-- No Clearing div! -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Why just trying to use css hack to do what 1 line of HTML do the job. And why not to use semantic html tu put break to return to the line?

Fo me is realy better to use :

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

And if you don't want any style in your html you just have to use class for your break

and put `.clear { clear:both; }` in your CSS.

Advantage of this:

- Semantic use of html for return to the line
- If no CSS load it will be working
- No need extra CSS code and Hack
- no need to simulate the br with CSS, it's already exist in HTML

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using this HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS that I would use:

```css
div#container {
    overflow: hidden;    /* makes element contain floated child elements */
}

div#content, div#sidebar {
    float: left;
    display: inline;    /* preemptively fixes IE6 dobule-margin bug */
}
```

I use this set all the time and it works fine for me, even in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

I always use the [**micro-clearfix**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) :

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

In [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/) I even apply it by default on block level elements. IMO, applying it by default on block level elements gives block level elements more intuitive behavior than their traditonal behavior. It also made it a lot easier for me to add support for older browsers to Cascade Framework (which supports IE6-8 as well as modern browsers).

Answer (score 2):

## Unlike other clearfixes, here is an open-ended one without containers

Other clearfixes either require the floated element to be in a well marked off container or need an extra, semantically empty `<div>`. Conversely, clear separation of content and markup requires **a strict CSS solution** to this problem.

The mere fact that one needs to mark off the end of a float, does not allow for [**unattended CSS typesetting**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340365/26348).

If the latter is your goal, the float should be left open for anything (paragraphs, ordered and unordered lists etc.) to wrap around it, until a "clearfix" is encountered. For example, the clearfix might be set by a new heading.

This is why I use the following clearfix with new headings:

```css
h1 {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This solution gets used extensively on [my website](http://hamwaves.com/capacitors/en/index.html) to solve the problem: The text next to a floated miniature is short and the top-margin of the next clearing object is not respected.

It also prevents any manual intervention when automatically generating [PDFs](http://hamwaves.com/capacitors/en/capacitors.letter.pdf) from the site.
Here is an [example page](http://hamwaves.com/capacitors/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also put this in your CSS:

```
.cb:after{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

*:first-child+html .cb{zoom: 1} /* for IE7 */
```

And add class "cb" to your parent div:

```
<div id="container" class="cb">
```

You will not need to add anything else to your original code...

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content{float:left;}
#sidebar{float:left;}
.clear{clear:both; display:block; height:0px; width:0px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">text 1 </div>
  <div id="sidebar">text 2</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"/>
```

I haven't had any problems with this method.

Comment: I think the point is we're trying to avoid both extra markup and inline styles with this solution. It depends which compromise your happiest with I suppose

Comment: The problem with this method is that in IE browsers the div has a height, so your spacing will be off. That is why the css methods set height and font-size.

Comment: you need to say <div style="clear:both"></div> with a proper closing tag to be propertly XHTML compliant. I've had jQuery issues when not doing this

Comment: Ironically, "supposed-to-be-self-closed" `<div/>` _is_ X(HT)ML compliant, but _isn't HTML compatible_, so for documents served as `text/html` all browsers will treat it as unclosed tag. There is no such thing like self-closing tags for `text/html` documents, _regardless of the doctype_, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

My Favourite Method is to create a clearfix class in my css / scss document as below

```
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

And then call it in my html document as shown below

```
<html>
  <div class="div-number-one">
    Some Content before the clearfix
  </div>

  <!-- Let's say we need to clearfix Here between these two divs --->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="div-number-two">
    Some more content after the clearfix
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

It is so simple clearfix clears the issue by when we using the float properties inside the div element.If we use two div elements one as float:left; and other one as float:right; we can use clearfix for the parent of the two div element. If we refuse to use clearfix unnecessary spaces fill with contents below and site structure will be broken.