# How can I interrupt a loop in CMD batch file using a specific key input?

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, break

here is the whole idea:
I have a menu to test ping different DNS Servers in a batch file just like below:

```
:MainMenu
ECHO 1. DNS Server 1
ECHO 2. DNS Server 2
```

Now when the user chooses one of the options above, the process starts to `ping` the selected server in this case I use google  DNS `8.8.8.8` :

```
:loopStarter
ECHO ***AUTO PING MODE IS ENABLED***
ECHO Pinging...
ping 8.8.8.8

CLS

GOTO loopStarter
```

As you can see this bunch of code creates a loop and `pings` the server and never stops,

**HOWEVER**

I want to stop the loop by entering a key (any key) to take me back to the `:MainMenu`

===========

I have seen and tested many answers like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728798/exiting-out-of-a-for-loop-in-a-batch-file) but unfortunately either I don't understand the code or it is not related to my problem.

I would appreciate it if anyone could guide me through.

Comment: The linked question is not relevant in your case. You need a parallel thread which detects a key press. And some form of notification to your main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this method found here to create a [dynamic menu](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php), you can create something like that :

---

```vbs
@echo off
:menuLOOP
Title Pinging some DNS
Color 9E & Mode 80,15
::===========================================================================
echo(
echo(
echo(       ***************************** Menu ******************************
echo(
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo            %%A  %%B)
echo(
echo(       *****************************************************************
echo( Make A Selection And Hit ENTER to Ping or simply hit ENTER to quit:
Set /p Selection= || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%Selection%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
:menu_[1] Ping DNS Server 1
Cls
ECHO( Pinging...
ping 8.8.8.8
echo( & echo( Type any key to return to the Main Menu
pause>nul
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[2] Ping DNS Server 2
Cls
ECHO( Pinging...
ping 8.8.4.4
echo( & echo( Type any key to return to the Main Menu
pause>nul
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this answer is most likely what I want  but i changed some parts of it

Answer (score 2):

A simple parallel thread example.
The :key_detector thread waits for a key, then it deletes the *notification_file*.
The :ping_test executes a ping, then it checks the existence of the *notification_file*, if it's still exists the loop will be repeated.

The threads are started by the two child instances of a pipe.
This looks a bit complicated, because you can't call a label directly inside a pipe, it just starts the own program and uses the trampoline at the beginning to jump to the label.

```
@echo off
REM *** This is a trampoline to jump to a function when a child process shall be invoked
for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") do goto %%L

set "notification_file=%temp%\keypress.tmp"

echo dummy > "%notification_file%"
call "%~d0\:key_detector:\..%~pnx0" | call "%~d0\:ping_test:\..%~pnx0"
exit /b


:ping_test
ping -n 2 8.8.8.8 
if not exist "%notification_file%" exit /b
goto :ping_test

:key_detector
for /F "tokens=1 skip=1 eol=" %%C in ('"replace /w ? . < con"') do @(
    set "key=%%C"
    del %notification_file%
)

exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

without getting into the entire 80+ lines of code i use for my ping test here is a short answer for the interrupt you are looking for.

```
:loopStarter
ECHO ***AUTO PING MODE IS ENABLED***
ECHO Pinging...
ping -n 1 8.8.8.8

choice /c xn /n /t 1 /d n >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto :EOF

CLS

GOTO loopStarter
```

I put `ping -n 1` instead of just `ping` so that it would ping just once then give a second to escape from the loop before running it again.  I have found that the pings usually are about 1 second apart so this maintains a similar timing.

Using the `choice` command the `/c` specifies the allowable characters, in this case x and n.  The `/n` tells it to not write to the screen the list of choices.  The `/t` tells how many seconds to wait before making a default choice, in this case 1.  The `/d` specifies the default choice, in this case n, which is the second option.  And the `>nul` makes it so that nothing gets written to the screen for this whole command.

Then the `if` statement checks to see if the first character in the list of choices was pressed and interrupts the loop if it was.

You could also use something like `choice /c abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 /t 1 /d a >nul` and `if %errorlevel% NEQ 1 goto :EOF`.  This would allow any character other than 'a' to be pressed to escape the loop.

Also, depending on the loop you are using this may not be feasible because it causes a 1 second delay between loops but I find for individual Pings that this is not an issue.